# How to Navigate to a New Webpage In Selenium?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I have the following code:

```
driver.get(<some url>)
for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('thumbnail'):
    element.find_element_by_xpath(".//a").click() #this works and navigates to new page
    element.find_element_by_link_text('Click here').click() #this doesn't
```

Which needs to navigate the following HTML (simplified of course) by clicking on a thumbnail, which directs to a new page, and then needs to click the `Click here` link in that new page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://iuytp.me/ns# fb: http://iuytp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Releases</title>
</head>

<body class="archive category category-releases category-4 custom-background">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="container" class="one-column">
            <div id="content" role="main">

                <h1 class="page-title">Releases</h1>

            <div id="thumbnail-post-display">
        <div id="thumbnail-post" class="post-7158 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-blog category-designer category-releases category-uncategorized">
            <div class="thumbnail"><a href="http://records.net/uncategorized/designer-7-inch-bufu-records-co-release/" title="Permanent link to Designer &#8211; 7 inch" rel="bookmark"><img width="300" height="300" src="http://records.net/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/dboypledge32-300x300.png" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="dboypledge3" /></a></div>
            <h2><a href="http://records.net/uncategorized/designer-7-inch-bufu-records-co-release/" title="Permanent link to Designer &#8211; 7 inch" rel="bookmark">Designer &#8211; 7 inch</a></h2>
        </div>
    </div><!--end thumbnail post display-->

            <div id="thumbnail-post-display">
        <div id="thumbnail-post" class="post-7107 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-blog category-releases">
            <div class="thumbnail"><a href="http://records.net/releases/people-2014-tour-demos/" title="Permanent link to All My People &#8211; 2014 Tour Demos" rel="bookmark"><img width="300" height="300" src="http://records.net/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/01_Doubt-mp3-image-300x300.png" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" /></a></div>
            <h2><a href="http://records.net/releases/people-2014-tour-demos/" title="Permanent link to All My People &#8211; 2014 Tour Demos" rel="bookmark">All My People &#8211; 2014 Tour Demos</a></h2>
        </div>
    </div><!--end thumbnail post display-->

            <div id="thumbnail-post-display">
        <div id="thumbnail-post" class="post-7089 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-blog category-releases">
            <div class="thumbnail"><a href="http://records.net/releases/sirens-blossom-talk/" title="Permanent link to Syrins &#8211; Boss Talk" rel="bookmark"><img width="300" height="300" src="http://records.net/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/sirens_final_smaller-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="sirens_final_smaller" /></a></div>
            <h2><a href="http://records.net/releases/sirens-blossom-talk/" title="Permanent link to Syrins &#8211; Boss Talk" rel="bookmark">Syrins &#8211; Boss Talk</a></h2>
        </div>
    </div><!--end thumbnail post display-->

            <div id="thumbnail-post-display">
        <div id="thumbnail-post" class="post-7073 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-blog category-releases">
            <div class="thumbnail"><a href="http://records.net/releases/worlds-strongest-man-scares/" title="Permanent link to World&#8217;s Tough Man &#8211; Sorry Scares You" rel="bookmark"><img width="300" height="300" src="http://records.net/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/a2312749950_10-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="a2312749950_10" /></a></div>
            <h2><a href="http://records.net/releases/worlds-strongest-man-scares/" title="Permanent link to World&#8217;s Tough Man &#8211; Sorry Scares You" rel="bookmark">World&#8217;s Tough Man &#8211; Sorry Scares You</a></h2>
        </div>
    </div><!--end thumbnail post display-->

            <div id="thumbnail-post-display">
        <div id="thumbnail-post" class="post-7046 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-blog category-releases">
            <div class="thumbnail"><a href="http://records.net/releases/sundog-space-criminal/" title="Permanent link to Dog &#8211; Space Criminal" rel="bookmark"><img width="300" height="300" src="http://records.net/dev/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Sundog_cover_high_res-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="dog_cover_high_res" /></a></div>
            <h2><a href="http://records.net/releases/sundog-space-criminal/" title="Permanent link to Dog &#8211; Space Criminal" rel="bookmark">Dog &#8211; Space Criminal</a></h2>
        </div>
    </div><!--end thumbnail post display-->

<div style="clear:both"></div>


        </div><!-- #container -->

    </div><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #wrapper -->

</div><!--#bg-wrapper-->

</body>
</html>
```

My code however spits out the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "crawler.py", line 17, in main
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Click here').click()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 254, in find_element_by_link_text
    return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 164, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'no such element\n  (Session info: chrome=35.0.1916.153)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267517,platform=Mac OS X 10.9.3 x86_64)'
```

The problem appears to be that the element isn't being updated with the contents of the new page. Replacing the problematic line's `element` with `driver` doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Please note that I must be able to do this for all thumbnails (hence the `for` loop).

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML code where you are trying this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out you need to store the links you want to navigate to in advance. This is what ended up working for me (found [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/selenium-users/iterate$20among$20elements/selenium-users/JtkpGD_TpYs/JJdp0Jg9Cz8J) to be helpful):

```
driver.get(<some url>)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h2/a")

links = []
for i in range(len(elements)):
    links.append(elements[i].get_attribute('href'))

for link in links:
    print 'navigating to: ' + link
    driver.get(link)

    # do stuff within that page here...

    driver.back()
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day!

Comment: Is there a way to do this and wait for javascript to be loaded for each page?

Comment: Good question, unfortunately I haven't touched selenium in years so I can't be of any help there.

Comment: I'm getting the error `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` how I can fix this?

Comment: I think you should ask a separate question regarding your new problem and link to this answer if it is what you based your attempt off of.

Answer (score 3):

Your first line:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('thumbnail'):
```

grabs all elements on the **first** page. Your next line:

```
element.find_element_by_xpath(".//a").click() #this works and navigates to new page
```

transitions to a completely **new** page, as you pointed out in your comment. At this point `element` is gone, so the next line:

```
element.find_element_by_link_text('Click here').click() #this doesn't
```

has no chance of doing anything as it refers to something that is not there. Which is exactly what the `NoSuchElementException` is telling you.

You need to start from the beginning, with something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Click here').click()
```

**Additional** answer:

To solve your iteration dilemma, you could take the following approach - please note that I am not familiar with python syntax! The below is Groovy syntax, you will have to adjust it to Python!

```
// first count the number links you are going to hit; no point in storing this WebElement,
// since it will be gone after we navigate to the first page
def linkCount = driver.findElements(By.className("thumbnail")).size()
// Start a loop based on the count. Inside the loop we are going to have to find each of
// the links again, based on this count. I am going to use XPath; this can probably be done
// on CSS as well. Remember that XPath is 1-based!
(1..linkCount).each {

    // find the element again
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='thumbnail'][$it]/a")).click()

    // do something on the new page ...

    // and go back
    driver.navigate().back()
}
```

Comment: Right, but how would I go about iterating through 'thumbnail' elements without having to specify a new `element` variable? Ideally I would like to be able to reassign/update the driver object to be updated with contents of the new page.

Comment: That sounds like a completely different question. If you search for web+scrape+python, you should be able to get many, many options.

Comment: So this is not possible with Selenium? I have to use another library like Beautiful Soup for this sort of thing? Selenium has many HTML parsing functions so I was hoping I would only have to use it for my HTML parsing/navigating needs.

Comment: Anything is possible! However, with 3.5k+ rep, you should know that your OP was answered, and you are now asking to solve a new problem.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to answer the question, however I need to know if this is possible to do with only Selenium in Python and your pseudo code doesn't really help in this case, considering using Selenium relies heavily on the API it exposes and your pseudo code doesn't address that aspect.

Comment: I think you need to have a look at what Selenium actually exposes. :( https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/index.html

Comment: +1, your edited answer got me on the right track. Thanks for your persistence in trying to help.