# How To Work Around StaleElementReferenceError: Element not found in the cache in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm using Selenium 2.53.1. I'm trying to select several elements that have the same xpath, but I keep getting a stale element reference error. I read in other posts that adding a wait would work, but I'm still getting this error.

```
browser.findElements(by.xpath("//a[@title='Run Test Suite']")).then(function(all_tests){
       // console.log(all_tests.length);
       for (var i = 0; i < all_tests.length; i++) {
           console.log(all_tests.length);
           all_tests[i].click();
           // browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300000);
           browser.findElements(by.xpath("//a[@title='Run Test Suite']"));
           console.log("got to my wait");
           browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
       }
});
```

Do you have any suggestions on what I did wrong?

Comment: I would recommend you spend some time learning what a stale element reference is. That's crucial to learning how to fix the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Click All Elements in Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805742/how-do-i-click-all-elements-in-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 0):

Do the click on `xpath` using an index, like
   `browser.findElement(by.xpath("//a[@title='Run Test Suite'][i]")).click();`

Note that i used `findElement` without the last `s` since i wand to find just one.

If using the index in that way is not working then you need to find a common parent, this index will work for elements on the same level.