# How to remove stale element reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

How do I resolve: 
`stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

> line 57, in 
>               print(lang.text)
>       selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page
>   document
>         (Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.108)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.16299 x86_64)

The [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003423/python-selenium-stale-element-fix) solution:

```
try:
except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        raise e
```

skips over the elements entirely

while waiting for a particular element does not remove error.  What am I doing incorrectly below?  Thanks.

**Script:**

```
import time
from random import shuffle

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://ubet.com/sports/soccer')

options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//select[./option="Soccer"]/option')
indexes = [index for index in range(len(options))]

shuffle(indexes)
for index in indexes:

    wait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//select/optgroup/option)[%s]' % str(index + 1)))).click()

    clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('.large-4:nth-child(1)   .lbl-offer   span  '))))




    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

    def find(driver):
        element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.row.collapse > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div > div.row.small-collapse.medium-collapse > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div.lbl-offer > span")
        if element:
            print(element)

            return element
        else:
            return False


    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(find)

    element_text = []

    for lang in element:
        print(lang.text)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: runs fine for me. no stale element error. on which line does the error come?

Comment: you should to use implicit/explicit wait as needed and before click check staleness

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory)