# Can't collect links from website (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing a program in Python to collect links from a website. The code is:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
for link in links:
     print(link.get_attribute('href'))
time.sleep(1)
```

I tried it in somes sites and it worked well. The problems is when I use in a specific site (www.ifood.com.br). It collect some links and then return some errors. I'm beginner in Python, so I don't know what they mean. Please, I need some help.

The result of the code:

> https://d1jgln4w9al398.cloudfront.net/imagens/ce/wl/www.ifood.com.br/favicon.ico https://d1jgln4w9al398.cloudfront.net/site/2.1.238-20181023.22/css/main.css https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800 https://www.ifood.com.br/
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\jorda\Desktop\Python - Projetos\digitar ifood.py", line 32, in print(link.get_attribute('href')) File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 143, in get_attribute resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name}) File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute return self._parent.execute(command, params) File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response) File "C:\Users\jorda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591088 (7b2b2dca23cca0862f674758c9a3933e685c27d5),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your error log you can see

`selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Generally, it happens when you are trying to interact with a web element that no longer exists in DOM. A typical scenario can be described as

1. You opened a web page.
2. Find some elements and saved them to a variable.
3. Page DOM is changed (for example reloaded).
4. You still see the same page but elements from step 2 are STALE from selenium perspective.

So in your case, you can try to make sure the page is fully loaded (i.e. does not restore DOM) before calling `.findElements`.
The simplest way to check if this will solve your problem is to add a sleep before calling .findElements.

```
time.sleep(5)
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@href]')
for link in links:
     print(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Please note that sleeps are not recommended to use. Because for example if 5 seconds works, for now, there is no guarantee that at some point (because of poor connection) it will not break your test. Instead, use a smart wait condition that will repetitively check for 'page loaded' condition and continue only when it happens. More details could be found here: [Python Selenium stale element fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003423/python-selenium-stale-element-fix)

Comment: It worked like a charm!! Thank you for all the explanation, it's very didactic! Now I need to learn how to print just the links I want, but this is another history. =)