# StaleElementReferenceException Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I just can't figure this out. It seems I've tried everything, from `WebDriverWait`, `try` `except` statements, `driver.implicitly_wait(60)` and everything in between.

My code has the following structure:

```
while True:
    element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath1)
    element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath2)

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    element1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath1)))
    element2 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath2)))

    if element1.text == 'some string': # get the exception here
        # do something 
    elif element2.text == 'some string': # or here
        # do something 

    driver.refresh()
```

I've tried implementing different expected conditions, none work. How can the element become stale between confirming it's visible to calling `.text`? Is it because the page is still loading? If so, how can I fix this?

**SOLUTION:** Ok, this seems to be working. If it fails at some point, I'll update this post.

```
while True:
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
        element1 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath1)))
        element2 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath2)))

        if element1.text == 'some string': # get the exception here
            # do something 
        elif element2.text == 'some string': # or here
            # do something
    except (StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException):
        continue

    time.sleep(30)
    driver.refresh()
```

Comment: Can it help you? You can also implicitly check "if element1 and element1.text == 'some string'". 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003423/staleelementreferenceexception-on-python-selenium

Comment: I've seen every stack overflow post on this by now haha. No luck. I've even tried `driver.implicitly_wait(60)`

Comment: And if you put if's into try-except blocks (each condition separately), than the code doesn't work as you want, right?

Comment: I just tried putting the `if-else` statements into a `try` statement with `continue` in the `except` block. Seems to be working