# Get this error when try to iterate using selenium. "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I write a python script. first, it visits this website. then click on the arrow on the right side and go to the new web page to collect some data. finally back to the previous page and do the same thing with next item.

Web page : https://register.fca.org.uk/s/search?q=capital&type=Companies

This is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time

url = 'https://register.fca.org.uk/s/search?q=capital&type=Companies'
service = Service('link to come driver')
service.start()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(12)


divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="result-card_main"]')
for d in divs:

   RN = ''
   companyName = ''
   companyName =   d.find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text
   RNData = d.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="result-card_figure-offset"]').text
   RN = RNData.split(':')[1].strip()

   d.click()
   time.sleep(12)

   phoneNumber = ''
   phoneNumberData =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="who-is-this-details-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]')
   phoneNumber = phoneNumberData[0].text.split('\n')[1]

   print(RN)
   print(companyName)
   print(phoneNumber)

   driver.execute_script("history.back();")
```

it givesme this Error:

```
  selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When you navigate away and go back, the references become stale. You want to find a way to iterate those that doesn't use element references

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StaleElementReferenceException on Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003423/staleelementreferenceexception-on-python-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way to avoid that error, change your code like this:

```
url = 'https://register.fca.org.uk/s/search?q=capital&type=Companies'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(12)


divs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="result-card_main"]')
for i in range(len(divs)):
   time.sleep(4)
   d = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="result-card_main"]')
   RN = ''
   companyName = ''
   companyName = d[i].find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text
   RNData = d[i].find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="result-card_figure-offset"]').text
   RN = RNData.split(':')[1].strip()

   d[i].click()
   time.sleep(12)

   phoneNumber = ''
   phoneNumberData =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="who-is-this-details-content"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]')
   phoneNumber = phoneNumberData[0].text.split('\n')[1]

   print(RN)
   print(companyName)
   print(phoneNumber)

   driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
```

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test it before. Now I did. For some reason your navigation "back" didn't work for me so I found a different way. I also found a wait is needed before trying to identify `d` in the loop. I updated the code with what works for me.

Comment: Comment: using hard sleeps is brittle and takes too long. You should look into using [webDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) in your test(s).

Comment: Thanks. it works. I will definitely add webDriverWait to it. :)

Comment: what kind of change I need to do in this code if I want to go next page and do the same thing again and again.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. If you're facing another issue, you can ask another question.

Comment: No issue with this code, this code collect data from page 1, so I try to reach page 2 using for loop & adding below code to it,

Comment: bt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="-pagination-next-btn"]')
bt[0].click()                                                                                                              it it gives same list index out of range