# How to scrape company names from a text file one by one, my code only scrapes the last company name on the list

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape company information from a company database. I have a list of companies in a text file, which I would want selenium to enter into the website's search and scrape the needed info one by one.

My problem is that for some reason it only enters the last name on the list for some reason. How would I be able to tell python to scrape the first company name on the list, then the next one and so on?

My code is the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# from typing_extensions import Self
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
# from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from time import sleep
from turtle import delay
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which

count = 0
file = open ("cegek.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    count += 1

# # cegek = "1000 Út Kft."

class HtSpiderSeleniumceg(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kamara'
    allowed_domains = ["wwww.ceginfo.hu/"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.ceginfo.hu'
    ]


    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

        #get login page

        
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://www.ceginfo.hu/")

        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys(line)
        sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys(u'\ue007')
        
        self.html = driver.page_source
        driver.close()

 #scrape needed info
    def parse(self, response):
        resp = Selector(text=self.html)
        for ceg in resp.xpath("(//div[contains(@class, 'd-flex flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between align-items-center')])[1]"):
            yield {
                'cegnev': ceg.xpath("(//h2[contains(@class,'s-title heading')])[1]/text()").get(),
                'adoszam': ceg.xpath("(.//span[@class='text-uppercase c-border me-lg-3'])[1]/text()").get(),
                'cegjegy': ceg.xpath("(.//span[@class='c-border'])[1]/text()").get()
            }
```

This is the exact format the company names list is in:

```
SZIMIKRON Ipari Kft.
Tigra Computer- és Irodatechnikai Kft.
Tradeland Kft.
Török László EV Török Kulcsszervíz
Tungsram Operations Kft.
Tutti Élelmiszeripari Kft.
Water and Soil Kft.
Webkey Development Kft.
ZDMnet
```

With some help, now the first name from the list is searched, but the spider does not scrape and breaks due to the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=100.0.4896.60)
```

This is my new code, at the bottom the # out part shows the supposed solution to my new problem, but I do not know how to implement it, I tried placing it in different places but it did not work. Also, I am unsure what the 'your_element' part is referring to, this solution was proposed in this thread:
[StaleElementReferenceException on Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003423/staleelementreferenceexception-on-python-selenium)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# from typing_extensions import Self
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
# from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from time import sleep
from turtle import delay
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

# # cegek = "1000 Út Kft."

class HtSpiderSeleniumceg(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'kamara'
    allowed_domains = ["wwww.ceginfo.hu/"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.ceginfo.hu'
    ]

    global names_to_search
    names_to_search = open("cegek.txt", "r").readlines()

    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
        self.driver.get("https://ceginfo.hu/ceglista/cegek")
        sleep(2)
        
        self.start_urls = [self.driver.current_url]
        sleep(2)

        global this_driver
        this_driver = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']")
        this_driver.send_keys(names_to_search[0])
        sleep(2)
        this_driver.send_keys(u'\ue007')
        sleep(5)


    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        print('this_driver')
        print(this_driver)
        print('names_to_search')
        print(names_to_search)
        
        for names in names_to_search:
            print('searching this names:')
            print(names)
            resp = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
            sleep(5)
            for ceg in resp.xpath("(//p[@class='mb-3 m-sm-0 meta d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row me-auto'])[1]"):
                yield {
                    'cegnev': ceg.xpath("(//h2[contains(@class,'s-title heading')])[1]/text()").get(),
                    'adoszam': ceg.xpath("(.//span[@class='text-uppercase c-border me-lg-3'])[1]/text()").get(),
                    'cegjegy': ceg.xpath("(.//span[@class='c-border'])[1]/text()").get()
                }
            try:
                print(this_driver)
                this_driver.send_keys(names)
                # driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys(line)
                sleep(2)
                this_driver.send_keys(u'\ue007')
            except:
                print('exception - do not break')
        self.driver.close()



        # my_element_id = "(//p[@class='mb-3 m-sm-0 meta d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row me-auto'])[1]"
        # ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException,)
        # your_element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions)\
        #                         .until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, my_element_id)))
```

Comment: What does the text file, cegek.txt look like?

Comment: company names under each other, one column

Comment: Please add it, formatted as it is in the file to your question.

Comment: What is the purpose of reading then lopping through your file but only counting, count += 1? You don't use line or count again in your code.

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: I am quite new to programming that part did not lead anywhere, unfortunately. Ultimately I am trying to come up with a way to scrape the company names on the website one by one. Where it says "line" in the send.keys section I would want that to be replaced by one company name, scrap it, then replace it with the next company name on the list

Comment: Ah, ok. So you need to read a line and get the name then pass that name to the website for the search?

Comment: Yes exactly, I would the code to automatically enter each name on by one and scrape them one by one, there could be a much more simple and easy way to do it for someone better at programming then the way I am attempting it

Comment: It definitely helped me get closer, now I am facing another issue in the code to which I found a thread that supposedly solves it, but for me, it did not, maybe I am putting the code in the wrong place or not utilizing it properly. The new problem is "selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document", I have attached my new code with your help to the original question.

Comment: You are passing this_driver.send_keys(names_to_search[0]) which will allows be the first element in the list [0]. You need to pass the 'names'.

Comment: @CaptainCaveman I managed to get the names loop working, now I am facing the problem that the names are being searched one by one but nothing is scraped. I started a new question thread for that, maybe you are able to help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71729880/17883928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't completely replicate your code without installing Selenium, web driver, etc, but this is how you would implement the solution.

Write a function to read names from cegek.txt and append to a list:

```
names_to_search = []

def get_names_to_search():
    # open file to read
    file = open ("cegek.txt", "r")
    # read lines in file
    lines = file.readlines()
    # loop through file and append names to list
    for line in lines:
        names_to_search.append(line.strip())
```

```
# The names_to_search list will contain:

['SZIMIKRON Ipari Kft.', 'Tigra Computer- és Irodatechnikai Kft.', 'Tradeland Kft.', 'Török László EV Török Kulcsszervíz', 'Tungsram Operations Kft.', 'Tutti Élelmiszeripari Kft.', 'Water and Soil Kft.', 'Webkey Development Kft.', 'ZDMnet']
```

Loop through `names_to_search` and pass each name to `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys(name)`

```
for name in names_to_search:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys(name)
```