# Code searches names in text file one by one but does not scrape any info, just goes from searching one name to the next

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a website that has information about companies, I have a text file with a list of companies that I would want selenium to enter into the website that is opened, and I want to scrape some info.

The code opens the website and goes through the names in the list, searching each one, but nothing is scraped.

The format of the text file:

```
Tradeland Kft.
Török László EV Török Kulcsszervíz
Tungsram Operations Kft.
Tutti Élelmiszeripari Kft.
Water and Soil Kft.
Webkey Development Kft.
ZDMnet
```

I suspect it is something related to the way I constructed the part where the names are searched one by one but I cannot figure it out, I am quite new to programming. My problem is that I am unable to loop in scraping.

The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# from typing_extensions import Self
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from time import sleep
from turtle import delay
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which

# # cegek = "1000 Út Kft."

class HtSpiderSeleniumceg(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'kamara'
    allowed_domains = ["wwww.ceginfo.hu/"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.ceginfo.hu'
    ]


    def __init__(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


        
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://www.ceginfo.hu/")

        with open('cegek.txt', 'r') as cegek:
            cegsor = cegek.readlines()
        for ceg in cegsor:
            cegsor.append(ceg.strip())
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys(ceg)
           
            sleep(2)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys(u'\ue007')
        
        self.html = driver.page_source
        driver.close()


#scrape needed info
    def parse(self, response):
        resp = Selector(text=self.html)
        while True:
            for ceg in resp.xpath("(//div[contains(@class, 'd-flex flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between align-items-center')])[1]"):
                yield {
                    'cegnev': ceg.xpath("(//h2[contains(@class,'s-title heading')])[1]/text()").get(),
                    'adoszam': ceg.xpath("(.//span[@class='text-uppercase c-border me-lg-3'])[1]/text()").get(),
                    'cegjegy': ceg.xpath("(.//span[@class='c-border'])[1]/text()").get()
                }
```

The code above scrapes information when this part is changed to only searching one name:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys("Tradeland Kft.")

sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys(u'\ue007')

self.html = driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Help would be appriciated!!!

Comment: Where are you passing each name to the send_keys()? We need to see the part that is not working. You should have a for loop that sends each name in: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='search']").send_keys("Tradeland Kft.")

Comment: The loop works now, but nothing is scraped so the 'def parse' part of the code is where the problem is, I suspect because for some reason it is out of the loop maybe. Names are entered one by one into the search and each one is searched, just no scraping