# Python Selenium: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, staleelementreferenceexception

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

# Find Search Element end Type Automation
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='sb_form_q']")
search_bar.send_keys("Automation")
time.sleep(3)

# Click Search Button
search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@id='search_icon']//*[name()='svg']")
search_button.click()
time.sleep(3)

# Clear Search Bar
search_bar.clear()
```

Why when I try to reuse search_bar( e.g:search_bar.clear() ) I always encouter problem:

```
StaleElementReferenceException Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

(Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.81)

Help please.

Error snapshot:

[image]

Error snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [StaleElementReferenceException on Python Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003423/staleelementreferenceexception-on-python-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you do `search_button.click()` DOM seem to be updated and so you need to re-define your `search_bar`:

```
# Click Search Button
search_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//label[@id='search_icon']//*[name()='svg']")
search_button.click()
time.sleep(3)

# Clear Search Bar
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='sb_form_q']")
search_bar.clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you identify the *search_button* and invoke click on it, the search results appear on the page. This change within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) also effects the previously located(found) elements, e.g. *`search_bar`*.

Hence, when you try to refer the previously located *`search_bar`* element, you see the error:

```
StaleElementReferenceException Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

---

### Solution

To *click*, *clear* or *send_keys* you have to locate the desired element afresh as follows:

```
search_bar = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='sb_form_q']")
```

Ideally inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) as follows:

```
search_bar = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='sb_form_q']")))
```