# Receiving a 'StaleElementReferenceException' in selenium - python, how do I handle this?

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am having an odd issue with sending keys to a text input bar in selenium. The weirdest part is I see the characters appear in the bar for a second before it disappears. I am sending each (string) key to the element via a `for` loop and you see the first few letters populate but then all of the sudden they disappear and then I receive a `StaleElementReferenceException` error. If I do `send_keys` without the loop, it ends up populating the entire word for a second and then disappears but it goes to the next step. I have to complete the whole form to be able proceed so I cannot just eliminate the step.

###### HTML I am trying to grab:

```
<input id="plaintiffDetails:city" name="plaintiffDetails:city" type="text" value="" 
onchange="jsf.ajax.request('plaintiffDetails:city',event,{execute:'@this ',render:'plaintiffDetails:additionalInfo ','javax.faces.behavior.event':'valueChange'})" 
maxlength="30" size="37"> == $0
```

I am unsure if the `onchange=` part is effecting this as I am unfamiliar with JavaScript.

###### Code:

```
        city_input = WebDriverWait(driver,10,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(\
            (By.XPATH, "//input[@name='plaintiffDetails:city']")))
        for c in client_city:
            city_input.send_keys(c)
```

###### The error:

```
StaleElementReferenceException            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 347
    344 city_input = WebDriverWait(driver,10,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(\
    345     (By.XPATH, "//input[@name='plaintiffDetails:city']")))
    346 for c in client_city:
--> 347     client_input.send_keys(c)
    349 wait()
    351 zip_input = WebDriverWait(driver,10,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(\
    352     (By.XPATH, "//*[@id='plaintiffDetails:zip']")))
```

Which is particularly weird because I had set `ignored_exceptions` to `ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)` as referenced to by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003423/staleelementreferenceexception-on-python-selenium). Yet, it still gave me that exception. Does anyone know why selenium is creating this exception/how to handle it?

Comment: Yes, onchange is firing that script... which looks like it's doing a lookup and probably displaying a list of matching options that you could click on.  When it updates that list, the DOM has changed so all element references are now stale.  One thing you could do is paste in the value.  (populate clipboard, and send keys of Ctrl-V)  The DOM would then update.  You need to re-get any element you are working with afterwards.  (maybe use a small sleep first or expected condition of stalenessOf...)

Comment: Interesting, I did not think of using selenium to copy and paste in general! There is no visible list I am selecting from however so where would I copy the value from. When you say re-get the elements I am working with- do you mean reestablish the element's variable? I am just wondering because once that element has the keys sent to it, it does not need to be interacted with again.

Comment: It sounds like the original send_keys('whole-text'); may have worked.  It sounds like if that ajax call finds a match it will fill out the rest of the form details, and submit them.  If you receive a "Stale Element" exception it means you can no longer use the current webelement reference. Retrieve that element variable (this is a reference to the DOM) again.  The DOM has updated making it stale.  Any method call on a stale reference will throw that Stale Element exception.  To use paste method, you'd set the clipboard's contents in your native language before Ctrl-V to element.