# Selenium Webdriver List with WebElements

Tags: java, selenium

Hello i have to save from a page same `<a>` in the page and has got as `class=my_img` i save this elements in a List an after i try to go in firts element of list and after go back get the second element but the selenium give me this error

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found
>   in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

and this is my code

```
    List <WebElement> Element = drivers.findElements(By.cssSelector(".my_img"));
    System.out.println("Megethos"+Element.size());
    System.out.println("Pame stous epomenous \n");
    for (i = 1; i < Element.size(); i++) {
        drivers.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(35, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(i+" "+Element.size());
        System.out.println(i+" "+Element.get(i));
        action.click(Element.get(i)).perform();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("go back");
        drivers.navigate().back();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        drivers.navigate().refresh();
        Thread.sleep(6000);

    }
```

Comment: Explained here http://stackoverflow.com/q/24775988/3124333 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the primary purpose is to click on the links and get back to the previous page, its better to **get "href" attributes for all the "a" elements in the page and navigate to each of them**. The way you've followed will always result in **StaleElementReferenceExeception**, as when you navigate back to the original DOM changes.

Below is the way like I suggested:

```
List<WebElement> linkElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@class='my_img']"));
System.out.println("The number of links under URL is: "+linkElements.size());

//Getting all the 'href' attributes from the 'a' tag and putting into the String array linkhrefs
String[] linkhrefs = new String[linkElements.size()];
int j = 0;
for (WebElement e : linkElements) {
    linkhrefs[j] = e.getAttribute("href");
    j++;
}

// test each link
int k=0;
for (String t : linkhrefs) {
    try{
        if (t != null && !t.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Navigating to link number "+(++k)+": '"+t+"'");
            driver.navigate().to(t);
            String title;
            title = driver.getTitle();
            System.out.println("title is: "+title);

            //Some known errors, if and when, found in the navigated to page.
            if((title.contains("You are not authorized to view this page"))||(title.contains("Page not found"))
                            ||(title.contains("503 Service Unavailable"))
                            ||(title.contains("Problem loading page")))
            {
            System.err.println(t + " the link is not working because title is: "+title);
            } else {
                System.out.println("\"" + t + "\"" + " is working.");
            }
        }else{
            System.err.println("Link's href is null.");
        }
    }catch(Throwable e){

        System.err.println("Error came while navigating to link: "+t+". Error message: "+e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your action.click() and/or navigate() calls are resulting in a page reload, causing the WebElement's in your list to no longer be valid. Put your findElements() call inside the loop:

```
List <WebElement> Element = drivers.findElements(By.cssSelector(".my_img"));
for (i = 1; i < Element.size(); i++) {
    Element = drivers.findElements(By.cssSelector(".my_img"));
    drivers.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(35, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(i+" "+Element.size());
    System.out.println(i+" "+Element.get(i));
    action.click(Element.get(i)).perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("go back");
    drivers.navigate().back();
    Thread.sleep(6000);
    drivers.navigate().refresh();
    Thread.sleep(6000);

}
```

Comment: This is correct answer however depending on the functionality of the application click on the element can be different