# Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, staleelementreferenceexception

I have been trying to run the following code in three different weblinks. Code works fine on one weblink. However, it throws an error message about "Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document". I looked into forum's two previous threads ([Python Selenium stale element fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003423/python-selenium-stale-element-fix) and [How to Navigate to a New Webpage In Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775988/how-to-navigate-to-a-new-webpage-in-selenium)) about the same error message but didn't get sort it out the issue.
Here is my code:

```
driver.get('https://github.com/avassalotti')
contributions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='filter-list small']//li") 
print(contributions)
for item in contributions:
    print (item)
    print(item.text)
    item.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    contribution = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class='f4 text-normal mb-2']").text
    print(contribution)
```

Program works for this link (https://github.com/alex) and does not work for (https://github.com/agronholm, https://github.com/avassalotti).

Any advice to fix the issue.

Comment: This is the perfect usecase you have to use WATIR, it perfectly regain the element once it has gone stale. I ran it in WATIR, It works perfectly. If you haven't gone too far in your project, you can use WATIR which sits on the top of Ruby Selenium Binding.

Comment: Try `for item in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='filter-list small']//li")` so that the list will be updated on each iteration

Comment: @Andersson I don't know Python, But Ruby has the similar for loop as well, It wouldn't execute the `driver.find_elements` every-time, it starts to execute on the collection which has been returned by `driver.find_elements` so it goes to stale for sure.

Comment: @Rajagopalan , Yep. of course. That was hasty decision :)

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the details of contributions avoiding ***stale element reference*** you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  years = []
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://github.com/agronholm")
  contributions = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='profile-timeline-year-list js-profile-timeline-year-list bg-white js-sticky float-right col-2 pl-5']/ul[@class='filter-list small']//li/a")))
  for item in contributions:
      print(item.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
      years.append(item.get_attribute("href"))
  for year in years:
      driver.get(year)
      print(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='js-yearly-contributions']//h2[@class='f4 text-normal mb-2']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
        2018


        2017


        2016


        2015


        2014


        2013


        2012


        2011


        2010


        2009


        260 contributions in the last year


        637 contributions in 2017


        770 contributions in 2016


        298 contributions in 2015


        239 contributions in 2014


        101 contributions in 2013


        113 contributions in 2012


        90 contributions in 2011


        16 contributions in 2010


        2 contributions in 2009
  ```
- Here you can find a detailed discussion on [StaleElementReference Exception in PageFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory)