# Selenium WebDriver crashes when I try to get innerText from an element container

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, staleelementreferenceexception

I am trying to get the innerText from all the`message.spoilers-container`, but when I scroll up the webpage, the program crashes, and give me an error.

Code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

def find_message_container(driver):
    try:
        elements = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelectorAll('.message.spoilers-container')")
        unique_texts = set()

        for element in elements:
            text = element.get_attribute("innerText")

            if text not in unique_texts:
                unique_texts.add(text)

            with open("unique_texts.txt", "w") as file:
                for text in unique_texts:
                    file.write("\n" + text + "\n")

    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print('Could not find the given element container. The following exception was raised:\n', e)
        pass
    
    return unique_texts
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\~\Desktop\Project\file.py", line 11, in find_message_container
    text = element.get_attribute("innerText")
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 179, in get_attribute   
    attribute_value = self.parent.execute_script(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 506, in execute_script   
    return self.execute(command, {"script": script, "args": converted_args})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.120)
```

What could cause this problem? The website I am testing this on is Web Telegram. Everytime new chats is loaded by scrolling up, a new container appears.

Any help would be helpful, I tried with some wait statements and wait.until, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a Web Telegram account so I can't test this but I would change these things:

1. The main issue is the `StaleElementReferenceException`. A stale element is an element that you assigned to a variable, the page changed, and then you try to perform a `.click()` or `.text` on the element. Once the page changes, the reference you had is gone... it now points to nothing. A quick code example of how this happens

   ```
   element = driver.find_element(locator) # got a reference
   # while doing stuff, page changes
   value = element.text # accessing the element using .text throws the exception
   ```

   To avoid this, you want to refetch the reference before accessing it

   ```
   element = driver.find_element(locator)
   # while doing stuff, page changes
   element = driver.find_element(locator) # refetch the element
   value = element.text
   ```

   In your case, this is happening because of the loop through the messages. You create your list before the loop so if the elements change while looping, the exception is thrown. The way to fix this is to refetch the elements within the loop.

   ```
   for element in driver.find_elements(...)
   ```

   One potentially big problem is that if you are in a fast moving chat with lots of new messages constantly, your script may not be able to keep up since the page DOM seems to change with each new message. NOTE: This is an assumption based on your comments.
2. Prefer the native API instead of using `driver.execute_script()` to find elements. Replace

   ```
   elements = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelectorAll('.message.spoilers-container')")
   ```

   with

   ```
   elements = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR('.message.spoilers-container'))
   ```
3. Use `.text` instead of `.get_attribute("innerText")`. Replace

   ```
   text = element.get_attribute("innerText")
   ```

   with

   ```
   text = element.text
   ```
4. Writing a file is a relatively slow operation. I would avoid writing until the loop is done.
5. Why are you returning `unique_texts` if you've already written them to file?

Here's my rewrite of your code based on these suggestions

```
def find_message_container(driver):
    try:
        unique_texts = set()
        for element in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR('.message.spoilers-container')):
            message = element.text
            if message not in unique_texts:
                unique_texts.add(message)

        with open("unique_texts.txt", "w") as file:
            for text in unique_texts:
                file.write("\n" + text + "\n")

    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print('Could not find the given element container. The following exception was raised:\n', e)
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The core exception is [StaleElementReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075477/7429447)...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

...which implies by the time [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) completes obtaining the *NodeList* of all of the matching elements in the document, some elements turns stale as new chats are loaded within a new container. In short the reference to the elements changes within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

---

### Solution

A possible solution would be to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".message.spoilers-container")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='message spoilers-container']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I already tried this, still gives me the same error. The problem is on the following line:
'text = element.get_attribute("innerText")'

Comment: @francomango Again _`text`_ is reserved keyword, an attribute, Within `for element in elements:` rename the variable _`text`_ as _`my_text`_

Comment: I don't understand, I understand that and tried to change the variable name to my_text, but still gives me exactly the same error?